# is there an alternative to window iteration in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm currently making automated tests for an application which opens up and uses **a lot of windows**. I'm trying to figure out a way to switch between these windows and focus in the most recent opened one but iterating through the window handles and comparing the title or URL is just **too slow** for us since this application opens so many windows!

Have you guys found a way to do this without the regular approach of getting the windowHandles and iterating through it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`getWindowHandles()` returns [LinkedHashSet](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.java) witch maintains insertion order. The last opened window will be the last item in the `Set`. The `Set` interface itself doesn't have an option to get last item but you can do something like

```
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
String lastWindow = windowHandles.toArray()[windowHandles.size() - 1];
driver.switchTo().window(lastWindow);
```

Comment: Well, actually I have found out that it does not maintain order! I saw it in other questions and forums and also recently saw it by myself in my code :-/

Comment: @ManoPajaro - if any solution works for you then you can add them as an answer as well so any one having issue in further can see the reference .. this is how stack works

Comment: @ShubhamJain I actually did not found an alternative, got stuck with the slow approach :(